# Linux: How to setup a local DNS resolver that can send query to multiple nameservers in parallel?

Tags: linux, dns

How to setup a local DNS resolver that can send query to multiple nameservers in parallel?

Why I need it:

- The reliability of 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 are not very good. (Observed hours of down or unstable time over last week for 1.1.1.1)
- The machine hosts https/socks5 proxy, so name lookup is crucial and quite frequently.
  Parallel look-up is preferred to reduce latency if one nameserver does not service.

The linux machine is ubuntu server 22.04.
The https/socks5 proxy service cannot handle multiple DNS server, so a local resolver have to handle the parallel or fallback look-up for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation this is possible using
[Dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

The parameter to use is:

> --all-servers
> By default, when dnsmasq has more than one upstream server available, it will send queries to just one server. Setting
> this flag forces dnsmasq to send all queries to all available servers.
> The reply from the server which answers first will be returned to the
> original requester.

You can do so by editing `/etc/default/dnsmasq` and adding `–all-servers`
to DNSMASQ_OPTS like so:

```
DNSMASQ_OPTS="--all-servers"
```

References :

- [Make DNS fly with dnsmasq –all-servers](https://ma.ttwagner.com/make-dns-fly-with-dnsmasq-all-servers/)
- [Parallel DNS lookup using dnsmasq](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429145802/https://jeanbruenn.info/2017/05/28/parallel-dns-lookup-using-dnsmasq/)
  (archive.org)

Answer (score -1):

DNSMASQ cannot do it by itself, but I saw Pihole ( which uses DNSMASQ behind the scenes ) being used with Unbound, giving you a recursive DNS server. Meaning that your server will ask the TLD Server directly and totally skip Google/Cloudflare.

Comment: Unbound will have terrible latency for non-cached queries. Recursive lookup is the total opposite of what OP asked for. Pi-hole is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm guessing said 'latency' is the waiting time for a DNS request to time-out, and not about the millisecond delay. OP is asking for reliability, as far as I understand it. Also - I'm not suggesting pihole, but dnsmasq - which is the underlying engine, and a great DNS server.